# select if join one table else join other table

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables. Lets call them a, b and c. Selected data from table a must be intersected with b or c depending of value of one cell in table a. Lets call this cell d. Is there way in MySQL to make query like:

```
SELECT
  a.cell,
  a.other_cell,
  a.d,
  alias.cell,
  alias.other_cell if(
    a.d = 3,
    left join b as alias on b.id = a.id,
    left join c as alias on c.id = a.id
  )
FROM
  a where a.id = 123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try for example [Conditional join as here](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/04/03/conditional-joins/) but instead `coalesce`, use `CASE WHEN`

In short:

> Instead, you simply LEFT OUTER JOIN to both tables, and in your SELECT clause, return data from the one that matches
>
> ```
> select
>   E.EmployeeName,
>   CASE
>     WHEN d = 3 THEN s.store
>     WHEN d <>3 THEN o.office
>   END as Location
> from
>   Employees E
> left outer join
>   Stores S on …
> left outer join
>   Offices O on …
> ```

NOTE I think the two columns must have the same type, at least in `PG`, not sure about `MYSQL`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want select from the different tables (`b` and `c`) based on a 'cell' value in
table `a` then something like this work may work for you.

```
SELECT
  a.cell,
  a.other_cell,
  a.d,
  if(a.d = 3, b.cell, c.cell) cell
FROM a
INNER JOIN b on b.id = a.id 
INNER JOIN c on c.id = a.id 
WHERE a.id = 123
```

This should join the all 3 tables provided the id in `b` and `c` also match the id in table `a`. The `if` function will select the `cell` column from table `b` or `c` based on the value of column `d` in table `a`.

Also helpful: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php